# Reverse engineering unknown binary data of .Factory file for Simplify3D

Tags: binary

To keep a long story short I'm in the process of trying to reverse engineer the .factory format this program called Simplify3D which is a 3D printing software slicer. I love the software but everything is closed source and I want a way for me to somewhat generate these files myself for automation purposes.

I did a small STL file into the software and exported this. If anyone knows anything related to what possible encryption was used and compression would be helpful. I tried looking at it myself and I feel some sort of encryption is used for sure as when I changed one parameter a lot of data seemed to change. Not sure as far as compression goes though.

Hex Data:

```
00 00 00 26 00 2F 00 4D 00 6F 00 64 00 65 00 6C
00 73 00 2F 00 4D 00 6F 00 64 00 65 00 6C 00 34
00 2E 00 69 00 6E 00 66 00 6F 00 00 00 9E 00 00
01 4C 78 9C B5 4C BD 0A C2 30 10 DE 03 79 0E 97
10 DA A6 4A EB 5A DD D4 C5 BA 05 E4 B0 A9 06 63
12 92 13 7C 7C D3 5A 84 2E 6E DE F2 DD F7 DB 6B
A3 2C 3C 14 DB DA EE DC 80 A7 A4 4F 8A 07 BC B1
66 2D 4F 51 85 28 DB A0 AD AE 54 27 37 2A DE D1
79 79 6C 77 8B 28 A7 06 4F 8C 92 6B 70 4F 7F 18
86 28 C1 00 36 1A 40 C5 F2 A2 E6 A2 12 25 CB B3
25 5F 89 BA 60 25 CF D2 51 12 2F 60 92 3F B2 39
50 12 1C 0E E5 EC A3 CE 60 34 F7 80 41 BF A6 F8
D7 FA FD FC 3F 4C C9 1B 37 31 50 CC 00 00 00 24
00 2F 00 4D 00 6F 00 64 00 65 00 6C 00 73 00 2F
00 4D 00 6F 00 64 00 65 00 6C 00 34 00 2E 00 73
00 74 00 6C 00 00 03 DE 00 00 14 A4 78 9C 95 98
CD 6B 53 41 10 C0 17 5A 7A 55 BC AA 90 7F C0 D6
AF 7A 10 9A 17 9E DA A3 20 5E 55 A8 68 68 C0 62
15 B1 2D 48 7D D0 5E 3C 58 A1 B7 1E 3C 08 FE 03
6D 6F 82 8D 15 8B 96 D2 34 35 46 7A D1 43 0F 2A
15 B5 A8 17 41 8C 6F B3 99 B7 33 BB 33 DB E4 9D
86 CC FC F2 66 F7 CD CE C7 9E 1B 1F BD 79 FB CE
F5 6B B9 AB 13 B9 8B A5 91 D1 1B A5 E2 C4 89 B3
B9 93 BD C7 7A 8F E7 8E E4 3A 7E 86 95 7E 92 B2
6A 3D A5 ED 7F 71 B1 F8 31 06 B9 D1 A8 67 F2 AD
DD 7A 5C AD CE E7 C3 04 58 D9 DF 93 82 4F 60 AB
FC CB 7A 5C 38 DC 17 85 09 D0 B8 C4 C6 5D ED 61
12 85 09 B0 D2 F2 C8 FE 7A FC EC E1 53 86 00 8D
96 4F CD BE 8B EF 1D 7C D5 81 57 98 68 34 6A F1
FB C5 0F 7B 78 05 56 5A 3E 7D A5 16 2F 3C DA 65
88 95 27 D5 A6 C6 10 1B 19 31 37 B7 22 78 05 1A
97 58 1D D9 68 7A 18 26 C0 4A CB B3 3F 2A C2 5E
81 BF 5A AE CE BF 8D 2F 1D FA DB C1 5E 61 A2 D1
D8 D4 D1 B3 07 01 56 9D AC DC 12 7D E7 37 9B EF
0B 13 60 85 77 DD 27 60 4F B4 7C F4 41 25 8B AB
F6 BC C2 C4 F2 40 A5 19 C7 61 02 AC EC EF E6 E1
08 23 63 62 66 5F 45 38 B5 98 00 2B B3 6F EB D9
3B EC BB B0 66 6D A6 E7 0C C8 AE 57 94 00 0D 26
B4 CC 12 91 D6 28 B5 9C 6A 5E 14 0C B1 DD 94 4B
DB 9F 62 F8 9D 12 58 E3 12 20 53 AF AC 55 D2 24
70 8C E1 D8 A5 04 7C 0F EB 61 E2 45 22 B7 72 97
00 6F 43 04 B6 92 BD A2 E7 03 13 B0 F2 BD 08 BC
0B 98 C0 51 62 77 17 EF A8 BB 0E 8E 48 3C C2 F5
CA 50 F8 9B BB 5F D3 DD 2B 97 48 0A AE 87 C4 AB
08 38 37 AE C0 0A 7F D9 30 81 BF 26 8E 2B 4A 80
C6 25 48 4E 14 09 B0 F2 BE 07 21 A4 13 45 CE 39
43 98 FF 85 EC A3 65 92 DB C5 77 C0 FF 86 F7 0A
BF 03 13 24 C3 89 04 58 61 0F 7D 02 FC D5 32 D4
A8 F6 BD C2 04 D4 C4 30 01 56 5A 26 D5 80 10 A0
D1 32 D4 8F F6 BD C2 04 A9 83 01 AF 8C 55 38 AE
68 2C 59 02 EA 6E 98 00 2B 2D 93 BE 84 10 A0 31
EF A8 65 7B D5 AE 57 96 80 CE 29 4C 80 95 96 49
0F 47 08 D0 68 19 BA BE F6 BD C2 04 74 99 61 02
AC EC EF E6 E1 08 23 63 82 F4 D4 22 01 56 66 DF
EA A4 72 1A 0A E7 57 9C 77 DD 5C 62 09 AC E1 09
BE 72 DA 79 00 64 77 E5 94 90 A6 09 4A 3C EE B9
1F AD 4D 2E 3C 77 3B 0B 29 C3 51 82 EB 5E DC DE
47 A9 9D C1 B1 E8 DB D4 F4 92 4B 48 F9 8A 12 5C
4F E5 F6 70 4A AD 77 0D 47 97 87 B6 3C 42 CA 70
94 E0 7A 43 DC 33 1A E2 D7 E2 85 E8 4B FD 40 D9
25 A4 DC 4E 09 A9 7B A5 C4 F7 EE FE E8 4F 77 BF
47 70 39 D8 27 B8 09 C2 9D 3F 94 4A 3D 8A 52 CF
3C 42 CA D4 94 E0 E6 1A 3C EF 18 62 7C 68 2B FF
BA 6B D8 23 A4 DC 4E 09 69 F2 A2 C4 CE D4 74 FE
EB E0 98 47 70 95 C1 27 B8 99 C3 9D 58 94 7A 33
B9 30 90 46 BC 47 48 F5 83 12 DC 24 E4 4E 5E 4A
AD A6 A7 89 23 A4 FA 41 09 6E A2 C3 93 5E B6 F2
25 58 39 26 A4 8A 43 09 69 E6 A4 C4 58 7A 9A E0
0B 62 82 AB 57 3E C1 CD E4 EE 44 AF D4 E7 F4 34
D9 48 AC A1 B8 E2 AB 1A 25 B8 9B 02 7C 83 60 88
9F E9 69 FA DD 3A 51 98 90 EA 20 25 A4 BB 0C 4A
68 8F 20 33 60 82 AB A2 3E C1 DD AA B8 77 32 69
EE 4E 77 B6 D8 CA 70 98 90 6A 2D 25 B8 BB 1E 7C
07 94 65 EA 32 64 6A 4C 48 B5 96 12 D2 6D 14 25
9A 91 DE AA 38 98 90 AB 33 26 B8 9B 34 5C 13 E1
81 7A 6E 67 35 DC 71 F8 95 D3 27 FC 1E C5 23 CA
40 E0 4E 1F DF 07 B8 73 AD 4B E0 D9 89 F6 A8 4A
FD 07 F2 BB B3 66
```

Comment: Nice work Bradley. I create a lot of multi-process prints in Simplify3D -- usually 20 processes or more. I've been looking for the format of a .factory file so that I can create a tool to position the parts and assign certain models to a specific process. Looks like I have everything I need in the XML file and the header file. Now I need to see if I can get binwalk to work in the Windows linux subsystem.

Answer (score 2):

Whilst binwalk approach from [@Bradley Heenk's answer](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/25510/reverse-engineering-unknown-binary-data-of-factory-file-for-simplify3d/25513#25513) will spot the compressed data streams and decompress them for you, the full top-level file format itself is quite simple to understand.  The the following will help anyone wanting to go both ways.

This file is a fairly simple compressed archive-type format.
The data for each contained file follows sequentially in the archive.

The first 4 bytes contain (in big-endian format) an integer length (in bytes) of the filename.

```
00000000: 00000026
```

The following specified number of bytes contain the file name (in either UTF16 or perhaps UCS2 format)

```
00000004: /Models/Model4.info
```

This is then followed by two 4-byte integers as follows -

```
0000002A: 0000009E    // compressed data size + 4
0000002E: 00000148    // uncompressed data size
```

Finally, the deflate compressed data stream is present (`78 9C` is a bit of a giveaway here) -

```
00000032: 78 9C B5 4C BD 0A C2 30 10 DE 03 79 0E 97 ....
```

The information for the next file immediately follow the compressed data stream.
This can be found here at offset `000000CC`

```
where 000000CC =   00000032 (start of compressed data stream)
                 + 0000009E (length read at offset 0000002A)
                 - 00000004
```

The second file then looks like this -

```
000000CC: 00000024                // length (in bytes) of filename
000000D0: /Models/Model4.stl      // filename
000000F4: 000003DE                // size of compressed data + 4
000000F8: 000014A4                // size of uncompressed data
000000FC: 78 9C 95 98 CD 6B ...   // compressed data
```

For the hexdump you provided these are the only 2 files.

The first `.info` file is text and corresponds to the 'Header File' in [the other answer](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/25510/reverse-engineering-unknown-binary-data-of-factory-file-for-simplify3d/25513#25513).

The `.stl` file itself appears to be a standard [Binary STL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STL_(file_format)#Binary_STL) format file.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like these files are compressed using basic zlib compression. Once extracted we can see that there seems to be different files one contains the XML information for various print settings. There is also one for binary information of which im assuming is the raw ASIC bytes for the STL file to be loaded externally which also has a header for the the model and position location for inside the software.

You should be able to take these files and run it through Binwalk using -Mre parameters to decompile these factory files and modifying the data and possibly compressing them back and reconstructing the factory file to load in the software.

**Binwalk Information:**
[image: Binwalk run-through]

XML File Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<profile name="Original Prusa i3 MK3/MK3S (modified)" version="2019-11-03 13:13:32" app="S3D-Software 4.1.2">
  <processName>Process1</processName>
  <groupName></groupName>
  <applyToModels>End_Cap</applyToModels>
  <baseProfile>Prusa Mendel (modified)</baseProfile>
  <printMaterial>PLA</printMaterial>
  <printQuality>0.10mm DETAIL</printQuality>
  <printExtruders></printExtruders>
  <extruder name="Primary Extruder">
    <toolheadNumber>0</toolheadNumber>
    <diameter>0.4</diameter>
    <autoWidth>0</autoWidth>
    <width>0.4</width>
    <extrusionMultiplier>0.95</extrusionMultiplier>
    <useRetract>1</useRetract>
    <retractionDistance>0.8</retractionDistance>
    <extraRestartDistance>0</extraRestartDistance>
    <retractionZLift>0.4</retractionZLift>
    <retractionSpeed>2400</retractionSpeed>
    <useCoasting>0</useCoasting>
    <coastingDistance>0.2</coastingDistance>
    <useWipe>1</useWipe>
    <wipeDistance>2</wipeDistance>
  </extruder>
  <primaryExtruder>0</primaryExtruder>
  <layerHeight>0.1</layerHeight>
  <topSolidLayers>10</topSolidLayers>
  <bottomSolidLayers>8</bottomSolidLayers>
  <perimeterOutlines>3</perimeterOutlines>
  <printPerimetersInsideOut>1</printPerimetersInsideOut>
  <startPointOption>3</startPointOption>
  <startPointOriginX>0</startPointOriginX>
  <startPointOriginY>300</startPointOriginY>
  <sequentialIslands>0</sequentialIslands>
  <spiralVaseMode>0</spiralVaseMode>
  <firstLayerHeightPercentage>150</firstLayerHeightPercentage>
  <firstLayerWidthPercentage>100</firstLayerWidthPercentage>
  <firstLayerUnderspeed>0.6</firstLayerUnderspeed>
  <useRaft>0</useRaft>
  <raftExtruder>0</raftExtruder>
  <raftTopLayers>3</raftTopLayers>
  <raftBaseLayers>0</raftBaseLayers>
  <raftOffset>1</raftOffset>
  <raftSeparationDistance>0.14</raftSeparationDistance>
  <raftTopInfill>100</raftTopInfill>
  <aboveRaftSpeedMultiplier>0.3</aboveRaftSpeedMultiplier>
  <useSkirt>1</useSkirt>
  <skirtExtruder>0</skirtExtruder>
  <skirtLayers>3</skirtLayers>
  <skirtOutlines>3</skirtOutlines>
  <skirtOffset>6</skirtOffset>
  <usePrimePillar>0</usePrimePillar>
  <primePillarExtruder>999</primePillarExtruder>
  <primePillarWidth>12</primePillarWidth>
  <primePillarLocation>7</primePillarLocation>
  <primePillarSpeedMultiplier>1</primePillarSpeedMultiplier>
  <useOozeShield>0</useOozeShield>
  <oozeShieldExtruder>999</oozeShieldExtruder>
  <oozeShieldOffset>2</oozeShieldOffset>
  <oozeShieldOutlines>1</oozeShieldOutlines>
  <oozeShieldSidewallShape>1</oozeShieldSidewallShape>
  <oozeShieldSidewallAngle>30</oozeShieldSidewallAngle>
  <oozeShieldSpeedMultiplier>1</oozeShieldSpeedMultiplier>
  <infillExtruder>0</infillExtruder>
  <internalInfillPattern>Rectilinear</internalInfillPattern>
  <externalInfillPattern>Rectilinear</externalInfillPattern>
  <infillPercentage>51</infillPercentage>
  <outlineOverlapPercentage>30</outlineOverlapPercentage>
  <infillExtrusionWidthPercentage>120</infillExtrusionWidthPercentage>
  <minInfillLength>2</minInfillLength>
  <infillLayerInterval>1</infillLayerInterval>
  <internalInfillAngles>45,-45</internalInfillAngles>
  <overlapInternalInfillAngles>0</overlapInternalInfillAngles>
  <externalInfillAngles>45,-45</externalInfillAngles>
  <generateSupport>0</generateSupport>
  <supportExtruder>0</supportExtruder>
  <supportInfillPercentage>30</supportInfillPercentage>
  <supportExtraInflation>1</supportExtraInflation>
  <supportBaseLayers>1</supportBaseLayers>
  <denseSupportExtruder>0</denseSupportExtruder>
  <denseSupportLayers>0</denseSupportLayers>
  <denseSupportInfillPercentage>20</denseSupportInfillPercentage>
  <supportLayerInterval>1</supportLayerInterval>
  <supportHorizontalPartOffset>0.3</supportHorizontalPartOffset>
  <supportUpperSeparationLayers>1</supportUpperSeparationLayers>
  <supportLowerSeparationLayers>1</supportLowerSeparationLayers>
  <supportType>1</supportType>
  <supportGridSpacing>1</supportGridSpacing>
  <maxOverhangAngle>45</maxOverhangAngle>
  <supportAngles>90,45</supportAngles>
  <temperatureController name="Primary Extruder">
    <temperatureNumber>0</temperatureNumber>
    <isHeatedBed>0</isHeatedBed>
    <stabilizeAtStartup>1</stabilizeAtStartup>
    <setpoint layer="1" temperature="205"/>
    <setpoint layer="2" temperature="200"/>
  </temperatureController>
  <temperatureController name="Heated Bed">
    <temperatureNumber>0</temperatureNumber>
    <isHeatedBed>1</isHeatedBed>
    <stabilizeAtStartup>1</stabilizeAtStartup>
    <setpoint layer="1" temperature="65"/>
    <setpoint layer="2" temperature="63"/>
    <setpoint layer="5" temperature="62"/>
  </temperatureController>
  <fanSpeed>
    <setpoint layer="1" speed="0"/>
    <setpoint layer="2" speed="100"/>
  </fanSpeed>
  <blipFanToFullPower>0</blipFanToFullPower>
  <adjustSpeedForCooling>1</adjustSpeedForCooling>
  <minSpeedLayerTime>15</minSpeedLayerTime>
  <minCoolingSpeedSlowdown>40</minCoolingSpeedSlowdown>
  <increaseFanForCooling>0</increaseFanForCooling>
  <minFanLayerTime>20</minFanLayerTime>
  <maxCoolingFanSpeed>50</maxCoolingFanSpeed>
  <increaseFanForBridging>1</increaseFanForBridging>
  <bridgingFanSpeed>100</bridgingFanSpeed>
  <use5D>1</use5D>
  <relativeEdistances>1</relativeEdistances>
  <allowEaxisZeroing>1</allowEaxisZeroing>
  <independentExtruderAxes>0</independentExtruderAxes>
  <includeM10123>0</includeM10123>
  <stickySupport>1</stickySupport>
  <applyToolheadOffsets>0</applyToolheadOffsets>
  <gcodeXoffset>0</gcodeXoffset>
  <gcodeYoffset>0</gcodeYoffset>
  <gcodeZoffset>0</gcodeZoffset>
  <overrideMachineDefinition>1</overrideMachineDefinition>
  <machineTypeOverride>0</machineTypeOverride>
  <strokeXoverride>250</strokeXoverride>
  <strokeYoverride>210</strokeYoverride>
  <strokeZoverride>210</strokeZoverride>
  <originOffsetXoverride>0</originOffsetXoverride>
  <originOffsetYoverride>0</originOffsetYoverride>
  <originOffsetZoverride>0</originOffsetZoverride>
  <homeXdirOverride>-1</homeXdirOverride>
  <homeYdirOverride>-1</homeYdirOverride>
  <homeZdirOverride>-1</homeZdirOverride>
  <flipXoverride>1</flipXoverride>
  <flipYoverride>-1</flipYoverride>
  <flipZoverride>1</flipZoverride>
  <toolheadOffsets>0,0|0,0|0,0|0,0|0,0|0,0</toolheadOffsets>
  <overrideFirmwareConfiguration>0</overrideFirmwareConfiguration>
  <firmwareTypeOverride>RepRap (Marlin/Repetier/Sprinter)</firmwareTypeOverride>
  <GPXconfigOverride>r2</GPXconfigOverride>
  <baudRateOverride>115200</baudRateOverride>
  <overridePrinterModels>1</overridePrinterModels>
  <printerModelsOverride></printerModelsOverride>
  <startingGcode>M115 U3.6.0 ; tell printer latest fw version,M205 X8.00 Y8.00 Z0.40 E1.50 ; sets the jerk limits mm/sec,G28 W ; home all without mesh bed level,G80 ; mesh bed leveling,G1 Y-3.0 F1000.0 ; go outside printing area,G92 E0.0,G1 X60.0 E9.0  F1000.0 ; intro line,G1 X100.0 E12.5  F1000.0 ; intro line,G92 E0.0,M221 S100,M900 K30 ; Linear Advance PLA,</startingGcode>
  <layerChangeGcode></layerChangeGcode>
  <retractionGcode></retractionGcode>
  <toolChangeGcode></toolChangeGcode>
  <endingGcode>M104 S0 ; turn off temperature,M140 S0 ; turn off heatbed,M107 ; turn off fan,G1 X0 Y200 F2000 ; home X axis,M84 ; disable motors</endingGcode>
  <exportFileFormat>gcode</exportFileFormat>
  <celebration>0</celebration>
  <celebrationSong>Take On Me</celebrationSong>
  <postProcessing>{REPLACE &quot;; feature outer perimeter\n&quot; &quot;; feature outer perimeter\nM204 S500\n&quot;},{REPLACE &quot;; feature inner perimeter\n&quot; &quot;; feature inner perimeter\nM204 S800\n&quot;},{REPLACE &quot;; feature solid layer\n&quot; &quot;; feature solid layer\nM204 S800\n&quot;},{REPLACE &quot;; feature infill\n&quot; &quot;; feature infill\nM204 S1250\n&quot;}</postProcessing>
  <defaultSpeed>2700</defaultSpeed>
  <outlineUnderspeed>0.6</outlineUnderspeed>
  <solidInfillUnderspeed>0.8</solidInfillUnderspeed>
  <supportUnderspeed>0.9</supportUnderspeed>
  <rapidXYspeed>10800</rapidXYspeed>
  <rapidZspeed>720</rapidZspeed>
  <minBridgingArea>50</minBridgingArea>
  <bridgingExtraInflation>1</bridgingExtraInflation>
  <bridgingExtrusionMultiplier>0.95</bridgingExtrusionMultiplier>
  <bridgingSpeedMultiplier>0.9</bridgingSpeedMultiplier>
  <useFixedBridgingAngle>0</useFixedBridgingAngle>
  <fixedBridgingAngle>0</fixedBridgingAngle>
  <applyBridgingToPerimeters>0</applyBridgingToPerimeters>
  <filamentDiameters>1.75|1.75|1.75|1.75|1.75|1.75</filamentDiameters>
  <filamentPricesPerKg>24.99|24.99|24.99|24.99|24.99|24.99</filamentPricesPerKg>
  <filamentDensities>1.25|1.24|1.24|1.24|1.24|1.24</filamentDensities>
  <useMinPrintHeight>0</useMinPrintHeight>
  <minPrintHeight>0</minPrintHeight>
  <useMaxPrintHeight>0</useMaxPrintHeight>
  <maxPrintHeight>0</maxPrintHeight>
  <useDiaphragm>0</useDiaphragm>
  <diaphragmLayerInterval>20</diaphragmLayerInterval>
  <robustSlicing>1</robustSlicing>
  <mergeAllIntoSolid>0</mergeAllIntoSolid>
  <onlyRetractWhenCrossingOutline>0</onlyRetractWhenCrossingOutline>
  <retractBetweenLayers>1</retractBetweenLayers>
  <useRetractionMinTravel>1</useRetractionMinTravel>
  <retractionMinTravel>2</retractionMinTravel>
  <retractWhileWiping>1</retractWhileWiping>
  <onlyWipeOutlines>1</onlyWipeOutlines>
  <avoidCrossingOutline>1</avoidCrossingOutline>
  <maxMovementDetourFactor>3</maxMovementDetourFactor>
  <toolChangeRetractionDistance>12</toolChangeRetractionDistance>
  <toolChangeExtraRestartDistance>-0.5</toolChangeExtraRestartDistance>
  <toolChangeRetractionSpeed>600</toolChangeRetractionSpeed>
  <externalThinWallType>1</externalThinWallType>
  <internalThinWallType>1</internalThinWallType>
  <thinWallAllowedOverlapPercentage>100</thinWallAllowedOverlapPercentage>
  <singleExtrusionMinLength>1</singleExtrusionMinLength>
  <singleExtrusionMinPrintingWidthPercentage>50</singleExtrusionMinPrintingWidthPercentage>
  <singleExtrusionMaxPrintingWidthPercentage>200</singleExtrusionMaxPrintingWidthPercentage>
  <singleExtrusionEndpointExtension>0.2</singleExtrusionEndpointExtension>
  <horizontalSizeCompensation>0</horizontalSizeCompensation>
  <autoConfigureMaterial name="PLA">
    <temperatureController name="Primary Extruder">
      <temperatureNumber>0</temperatureNumber>
      <isHeatedBed>0</isHeatedBed>
      <stabilizeAtStartup>1</stabilizeAtStartup>
      <setpoint layer="1" temperature="205"/>
      <setpoint layer="2" temperature="200"/>
    </temperatureController>
    <temperatureController name="Heated Bed">
      <temperatureNumber>0</temperatureNumber>
      <isHeatedBed>1</isHeatedBed>
      <stabilizeAtStartup>1</stabilizeAtStartup>
      <setpoint layer="1" temperature="65"/>
      <setpoint layer="2" temperature="63"/>
      <setpoint layer="5" temperature="62"/>
    </temperatureController>
    <globalExtrusionMultiplier>0.95</globalExtrusionMultiplier>
    <fanSpeed>
      <setpoint layer="1" speed="0"/>
      <setpoint layer="2" speed="100"/>
    </fanSpeed>
    <increaseFanForBridging>1</increaseFanForBridging>
    <bridgingFanSpeed>100</bridgingFanSpeed>
    <startingGcode>M115 U3.6.0 ; tell printer latest fw version,M205 X8.00 Y8.00 Z0.40 E1.50 ; sets the jerk limits mm/sec,G28 W ; home all without mesh bed level,G80 ; mesh bed leveling,G1 Y-3.0 F1000.0 ; go outside printing area,G92 E0.0,G1 X60.0 E9.0  F1000.0 ; intro line,G1 X100.0 E12.5  F1000.0 ; intro line,G92 E0.0,M221 S100,M900 K30 ; Linear Advance PLA,</startingGcode>
    <filamentPricesPerKg>24.99|24.99|24.99|24.99|24.99|24.99</filamentPricesPerKg>
    <filamentDensities>1.25|1.24|1.24|1.24|1.24|1.24</filamentDensities>
  </autoConfigureMaterial>
  <autoConfigureMaterial name="ABS">
    <temperatureController name="Primary Extruder">
      <temperatureNumber>0</temperatureNumber>
      <isHeatedBed>0</isHeatedBed>
      <stabilizeAtStartup>1</stabilizeAtStartup>
      <setpoint layer="1" temperature="240"/>
    </temperatureController>
    <temperatureController name="Heated Bed">
      <temperatureNumber>0</temperatureNumber>
      <isHeatedBed>1</isHeatedBed>
      <stabilizeAtStartup>1</stabilizeAtStartup>
      <setpoint layer="1" temperature="100"/>
    </temperatureController>
    <globalExtrusionMultiplier>0.95</globalExtrusionMultiplier>
    <fanSpeed>
      <setpoint layer="1" speed="0"/>
    </fanSpeed>
    <increaseFanForBridging>1</increaseFanForBridging>
    <bridgingFanSpeed>30</bridgingFanSpeed>
    <startingGcode>M115 U3.6.0 ; tell printer latest fw version,M205 X8.00 Y8.00 Z0.40 E1.50 ; sets the jerk limits mm/sec,G28 W ; home all without mesh bed level,G80 ; mesh bed leveling,G1 Y-3.0 F1000.0 ; go outside printing area,G92 E0.0,G1 X60.0 E9.0  F1000.0 ; intro line,G1 X100.0 E12.5  F1000.0 ; intro line,G92 E0.0,M221 S100,M900 K30 ; Linear Advance ABS,</startingGcode>
    <filamentPricesPerKg>27.82|27.82|27.82|27.82|27.82|27.82</filamentPricesPerKg>
    <filamentDensities>1.08|1.08|1.08|1.08|1.08|1.08</filamentDensities>
  </autoConfigureMaterial>
  <autoConfigureMaterial name="PET">
    <temperatureController name="Primary Extruder">
      <temperatureNumber>0</temperatureNumber>
      <isHeatedBed>0</isHeatedBed>
      <stabilizeAtStartup>1</stabilizeAtStartup>
      <setpoint layer="1" temperature="230"/>
      <setpoint layer="2" temperature="240"/>
    </temperatureController>
    <temperatureController name="Heated Bed">
      <temperatureNumber>0</temperatureNumber>
      <isHeatedBed>1</isHeatedBed>
      <stabilizeAtStartup>1</stabilizeAtStartup>
      <setpoint layer="1" temperature="85"/>
      <setpoint layer="2" temperature="90"/>
    </temperatureController>
    <globalExtrusionMultiplier>0.95</globalExtrusionMultiplier>
    <fanSpeed>
      <setpoint layer="1" speed="0"/>
      <setpoint layer="4" speed="50"/>
    </fanSpeed>
    <increaseFanForBridging>1</increaseFanForBridging>
    <bridgingFanSpeed>50</bridgingFanSpeed>
    <startingGcode>M115 U3.6.0 ; tell printer latest fw version,M205 X8.00 Y8.00 Z0.40 E1.50 ; sets the jerk limits mm/sec,G28 W ; home all without mesh bed level,G80 ; mesh bed leveling,G1 Y-3.0 F1000.0 ; go outside printing area,G92 E0.0,G1 X60.0 E9.0  F1000.0 ; intro line,G1 X100.0 E12.5  F1000.0 ; intro line,G92 E0.0,M221 S100,M900 K45 ; Linear Advance PET,</startingGcode>
    <filamentPricesPerKg>29.99|29.99|29.99|29.99|29.99|29.99</filamentPricesPerKg>
    <filamentDensities>1.27|1.27|1.27|1.27|1.27|1.27</filamentDensities>
  </autoConfigureMaterial>
  <autoConfigureMaterial name="ColorFabb XT">
    <globalExtruderTemperature>250</globalExtruderTemperature>
    <globalBedTemperature>85</globalBedTemperature>
    <globalExtrusionMultiplier>0.95</globalExtrusionMultiplier>
    <fanSpeed>
      <setpoint layer="1" speed="0"/>
      <setpoint layer="4" speed="50"/>
    </fanSpeed>
    <increaseFanForBridging>1</increaseFanForBridging>
    <bridgingFanSpeed>50</bridgingFanSpeed>
    <startingGcode>M115 U3.6.0 ; tell printer latest fw version,M205 X8.00 Y8.00 Z0.40 E1.50 ; sets the jerk limits mm/sec,G28 W ; home all without mesh bed level,G80 ; mesh bed leveling,G1 Y-3.0 F1000.0 ; go outside printing area,G92 E0.0,G1 X60.0 E9.0  F1000.0 ; intro line,G1 X100.0 E12.5  F1000.0 ; intro line,G92 E0.0,M221 S100,M900 K45 ; Linear Advance PET,</startingGcode>
    <filamentPricesPerKg>39.95|39.95|39.95|39.95|39.95|39.95</filamentPricesPerKg>
    <filamentDensities>1.27|1.27|1.27|1.27|1.27|1.27</filamentDensities>
  </autoConfigureMaterial>
  <autoConfigureQuality name="0.10mm DETAIL">
    <layerHeight>0.1</layerHeight>
    <firstLayerHeightPercentage>150</firstLayerHeightPercentage>
    <firstLayerWidthPercentage>100</firstLayerWidthPercentage>
    <topSolidLayers>10</topSolidLayers>
    <bottomSolidLayers>8</bottomSolidLayers>
    <skirtLayers>3</skirtLayers>
    <infillPercentage>51</infillPercentage>
    <supportInfillPercentage>30</supportInfillPercentage>
    <defaultSpeed>2700</defaultSpeed>
    <outlineUnderspeed>0.6</outlineUnderspeed>
    <solidInfillUnderspeed>0.8</solidInfillUnderspeed>
    <supportUnderspeed>0.9</supportUnderspeed>
    <infillExtrusionWidthPercentage>120</infillExtrusionWidthPercentage>
    <postProcessing>{REPLACE &quot;; feature outer perimeter\n&quot; &quot;; feature outer perimeter\nM204 S500\n&quot;},{REPLACE &quot;; feature inner perimeter\n&quot; &quot;; feature inner perimeter\nM204 S800\n&quot;},{REPLACE &quot;; feature solid layer\n&quot; &quot;; feature solid layer\nM204 S800\n&quot;},{REPLACE &quot;; feature infill\n&quot; &quot;; feature infill\nM204 S1250\n&quot;}</postProcessing>
    <perimeterOutlines>3</perimeterOutlines>
    <firstLayerUnderspeed>0.6</firstLayerUnderspeed>
    <minSpeedLayerTime>15</minSpeedLayerTime>
    <minCoolingSpeedSlowdown>40</minCoolingSpeedSlowdown>
    <extruder name="Primary Extruder">
      <toolheadNumber>0</toolheadNumber>
      <diameter>0.4</diameter>
      <autoWidth>0</autoWidth>
      <width>0.4</width>
      <extrusionMultiplier>0.95</extrusionMultiplier>
      <useRetract>1</useRetract>
      <retractionDistance>0.8</retractionDistance>
      <extraRestartDistance>0</extraRestartDistance>
      <retractionZLift>0.4</retractionZLift>
      <retractionSpeed>2400</retractionSpeed>
      <useCoasting>0</useCoasting>
      <coastingDistance>0.2</coastingDistance>
      <useWipe>1</useWipe>
      <wipeDistance>2</wipeDistance>
    </extruder>
  </autoConfigureQuality>
  <autoConfigureQuality name="0.15mm OPTIMAL">
    <layerHeight>0.15</layerHeight>
    <firstLayerHeightPercentage>100</firstLayerHeightPercentage>
    <firstLayerWidthPercentage>100</firstLayerWidthPercentage>
    <topSolidLayers>8</topSolidLayers>
    <bottomSolidLayers>5</bottomSolidLayers>
    <skirtLayers>3</skirtLayers>
    <infillPercentage>20</infillPercentage>
    <supportInfillPercentage>30</supportInfillPercentage>
    <defaultSpeed>3600</defaultSpeed>
    <outlineUnderspeed>0.5</outlineUnderspeed>
    <solidInfillUnderspeed>0.65</solidInfillUnderspeed>
    <supportUnderspeed>0.8</supportUnderspeed>
    <infillExtrusionWidthPercentage>100</infillExtrusionWidthPercentage>
    <postProcessing>{REPLACE &quot;; feature outer perimeter\n&quot; &quot;; feature outer perimeter\nM204 S800\n&quot;},{REPLACE &quot;; feature inner perimeter\n&quot; &quot;; feature inner perimeter\nM204 S1000\n&quot;},{REPLACE &quot;; feature solid layer\n&quot; &quot;; feature solid layer\nM204 S1000\n&quot;},{REPLACE &quot;; feature infill\n&quot; &quot;; feature infill\nM204 S1250\n&quot;}</postProcessing>
    <perimeterOutlines>2</perimeterOutlines>
    <firstLayerUnderspeed>0.45</firstLayerUnderspeed>
    <minSpeedLayerTime>15</minSpeedLayerTime>
    <minCoolingSpeedSlowdown>35</minCoolingSpeedSlowdown>
    <extruder name="Primary Extruder">
      <toolheadNumber>0</toolheadNumber>
      <diameter>0.4</diameter>
      <autoWidth>1</autoWidth>
      <width>0.48</width>
      <extrusionMultiplier>0.95</extrusionMultiplier>
      <useRetract>1</useRetract>
      <retractionDistance>0.8</retractionDistance>
      <extraRestartDistance>0</extraRestartDistance>
      <retractionZLift>0.4</retractionZLift>
      <retractionSpeed>2400</retractionSpeed>
      <useCoasting>0</useCoasting>
      <coastingDistance>0.2</coastingDistance>
      <useWipe>1</useWipe>
      <wipeDistance>2</wipeDistance>
    </extruder>
  </autoConfigureQuality>
  <autoConfigureQuality name="0.20mm NORMAL">
    <layerHeight>0.2</layerHeight>
    <firstLayerHeightPercentage>60</firstLayerHeightPercentage>
    <firstLayerWidthPercentage>100</firstLayerWidthPercentage>
    <topSolidLayers>5</topSolidLayers>
    <bottomSolidLayers>4</bottomSolidLayers>
    <skirtLayers>1</skirtLayers>
    <infillPercentage>30</infillPercentage>
    <supportInfillPercentage>20</supportInfillPercentage>
    <defaultSpeed>3600</defaultSpeed>
    <outlineUnderspeed>0.5</outlineUnderspeed>
    <solidInfillUnderspeed>0.65</solidInfillUnderspeed>
    <supportUnderspeed>0.8</supportUnderspeed>
    <infillExtrusionWidthPercentage>100</infillExtrusionWidthPercentage>
    <postProcessing>{REPLACE &quot;; feature outer perimeter\n&quot; &quot;; feature outer perimeter\nM204 S800\n&quot;},{REPLACE &quot;; feature inner perimeter\n&quot; &quot;; feature inner perimeter\nM204 S1000\n&quot;},{REPLACE &quot;; feature solid layer\n&quot; &quot;; feature solid layer\nM204 S1000\n&quot;},{REPLACE &quot;; feature infill\n&quot; &quot;; feature infill\nM204 S1250\n&quot;}</postProcessing>
    <perimeterOutlines>3</perimeterOutlines>
    <firstLayerUnderspeed>0.6</firstLayerUnderspeed>
    <minSpeedLayerTime>15</minSpeedLayerTime>
    <minCoolingSpeedSlowdown>35</minCoolingSpeedSlowdown>
    <extruder name="Primary Extruder">
      <toolheadNumber>0</toolheadNumber>
      <diameter>0.4</diameter>
      <autoWidth>0</autoWidth>
      <width>0.5</width>
      <extrusionMultiplier>0.95</extrusionMultiplier>
      <useRetract>1</useRetract>
      <retractionDistance>0.8</retractionDistance>
      <extraRestartDistance>0</extraRestartDistance>
      <retractionZLift>0.4</retractionZLift>
      <retractionSpeed>2400</retractionSpeed>
      <useCoasting>0</useCoasting>
      <coastingDistance>0.2</coastingDistance>
      <useWipe>1</useWipe>
      <wipeDistance>2</wipeDistance>
    </extruder>
  </autoConfigureQuality>
  <autoConfigureQuality name="0.30mm FAST">
    <layerHeight>0.3</layerHeight>
    <firstLayerHeightPercentage>50</firstLayerHeightPercentage>
    <firstLayerWidthPercentage>100</firstLayerWidthPercentage>
    <topSolidLayers>3</topSolidLayers>
    <bottomSolidLayers>3</bottomSolidLayers>
    <skirtLayers>2</skirtLayers>
    <infillPercentage>100</infillPercentage>
    <supportInfillPercentage>30</supportInfillPercentage>
    <defaultSpeed>3600</defaultSpeed>
    <outlineUnderspeed>0.7</outlineUnderspeed>
    <solidInfillUnderspeed>0.65</solidInfillUnderspeed>
    <supportUnderspeed>0.8</supportUnderspeed>
    <infillExtrusionWidthPercentage>100</infillExtrusionWidthPercentage>
    <postProcessing>{REPLACE &quot;; feature outer perimeter\n&quot; &quot;; feature outer perimeter\nM204 S800\n&quot;},{REPLACE &quot;; feature inner perimeter\n&quot; &quot;; feature inner perimeter\nM204 S1000\n&quot;},{REPLACE &quot;; feature solid layer\n&quot; &quot;; feature solid layer\nM204 S1000\n&quot;},{REPLACE &quot;; feature infill\n&quot; &quot;; feature infill\nM204 S1250\n&quot;}</postProcessing>
    <perimeterOutlines>3</perimeterOutlines>
    <firstLayerUnderspeed>0.45</firstLayerUnderspeed>
    <minSpeedLayerTime>15</minSpeedLayerTime>
    <minCoolingSpeedSlowdown>35</minCoolingSpeedSlowdown>
    <extruder name="Primary Extruder">
      <toolheadNumber>0</toolheadNumber>
      <diameter>0.4</diameter>
      <autoWidth>0</autoWidth>
      <width>0.5</width>
      <extrusionMultiplier>0.97</extrusionMultiplier>
      <useRetract>1</useRetract>
      <retractionDistance>0.8</retractionDistance>
      <extraRestartDistance>0</extraRestartDistance>
      <retractionZLift>0</retractionZLift>
      <retractionSpeed>2400</retractionSpeed>
      <useCoasting>0</useCoasting>
      <coastingDistance>0.2</coastingDistance>
      <useWipe>1</useWipe>
      <wipeDistance>2</wipeDistance>
    </extruder>
  </autoConfigureQuality>
</profile>
```

Header File:

```
filename,End_Cap
filepath,C:\Users\Trini8ed\Desktop\STL's\End_Cap.STL
groupName,
translate,129.3834,105.6392,4.0000
scale,1.0000,1.0000,1.0000
rotate,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000
rotMatrix,1.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,1.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,1.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,1.000000
```

*And yes I may have answered my own question .-.*